# Как сделать условие на выдачу ошибки python

Tags: python, парсер, циклы, selenium

Есть код:

```
def getId():
        i=1
        while not ('Тут должна быть ошибка'):
            ids.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="feed_rows"]/div['+str(i)+']/div').get_attribute('data-post-id'))
            i=i+1
        return ids
```

Этот код парсит id-шники, количество (i) которых может увеличиваться, и когда i становится больше, чем кол-во айдишников, выводится ошибка.
Вопрос - как эту ошибку сделать условием к циклу? Спасибо.

UPD:

```
 import time;
from selenium import webdriver
import re

driver= webdriver.Chrome("C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe")//тут расположение ChromeDriver'a
driver.get("http:\\www.vk.com")
login = driver.find_element_by_id('index_email')
login.send_keys('сюда записать логин от вк - подставится в соответствующее поле')
password = driver.find_element_by_id('index_pass')
password.send_keys('здесь пароль от вк ')
button = driver.find_element_by_id('index_login_button')
button.click()
driver.get('http:\\www.vk.com/feed')
time.sleep(3)
ids = []
def getId():
    i=1
    while not ('код ошибки'):
        ids.append(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="feed_rows"]/div['+str(i)+']/div').get_attribute('data-post-id'))
        i=i+1
    return ids
```

Comment: Вы какой `exception` ожидаете?

Comment: Можете привести [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример данных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Можно подробнее, что это? Полный код программы? Или данные, которые нужны для ее работы?

Comment: трудно будет объяснить вам более развернуто, чем это сделано по ссылке, которую я привел. Вы же ее прочитали? ;)

Comment: Разумеется прочитал. Смотрите, какая проблема - для ее использования нужен Selenium и ChromeWebDriver. Есть у вас такое есть, то я бы не отказался от помощи, ну а если нет - то пойму :)

Comment: Поставить `selenium` - дело 10 секунд. Если привести в вопросе минимальный, самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример вероятность получения проверенного ответа __значительно__ увеличивается. А дальше уже вам решать... Кстати а то что вам предложили в ответах не подходит?

Comment: Нет, оно не завелось. Сейчас попробую отредактировать сам вопрос, добавив туда минимальный и блабла пример. Спасибо, что тратите на меня свое время :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял i - это счетчик div у родителя.

Сначала найдем главный блок

```
def get_id():
    ids = []
    main = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#feed_rows')
    divs = main.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.feed_row>div')
    print(len(divs))
    for div in divs:
        if(div.get_attribute('data-post-id') != None):
            ids.append(div.get_attribute('data-post-id'))
    return ids
```

Comment: Я имел ввиду счетчик, для определения n-ного потомка, странная какая конструкция. К тому же while медленнее чем for

Comment: Это очень близко к тому, что мне надо. Но выводит это: http://prntscr.com/ll8igl  Сейчас попробую поменять что-нибудь в выражениях, возможно стоит уйти от поиска по селектору к поиску по Xpath

Comment: Так попробуйте.

Comment: Всё равно выводит много "None". CSS- селектор только что проверил в Chrome через поиск по коду, все прекрасно находит.

Comment: Нашел "дубовое" решение - добавил условие http://prntscr.com/ll8rw4 Но теперь нашлась еще одна проблема - иногда он собирает дважды один и тот же Id.

Comment: @terequell Обновил

Comment: Только не легче это было сделать через api?

Comment: Вы правы - это гораздо легче сделать через API. Больше скажу - любой нормальный человек сделал бы это через API. Но условие задачи предусматривает парсить строго Селениумом :(